# Injection from $WC(E/K)$ to $H^1(G_K,E)$ from Silverman's 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves'

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

This is question regarding Silverman's 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves'(AEC), p325, theorem 3.6.

I want prove there is bijection between $WC(E/K)$ and $H^1(G_K,E)$.

The bijection is given by {$C/K$}→{$σ→p_0^σ-p_0$}.

To prove injectivity,  Suppose copyables $p_0^σ-p_0$ and $p_0'^σ-p_0'$ corresponding to $C/K$ and $C'/K$ are cohomologous.

Then, AEC reads $θ:C→C', θ(p)＝p_0'+(p-p_0) +P_0$  gives the isomorphism.

AEC reads '**It is clear that θ is a $\overline{K}$-isomorphism**'.

My question is ; Why θ is a $\overline{K}$-isomorphism ?
I tried to find inverse, but the middle one $+(p-p_0)$ is not isomorphism, so I'm confused.

Comment: $C$ and $C'$ are elliptic curves isomorphic to $E$ over $\overline{K}$ so it is immediate that $\theta$ is an isomorphism over $\overline{K}$.

Comment: Could you give a bit more explanation ? Why both $C$,$C'$ are twists of $E$ implies θ is isom ?

Comment: It is part of the definition of principal homogeneous space that $C$ is isomorphic to $E$ over $\overline{K}$ once you fix a point of $C$, the isomorphism is denoted $+$. Another one $C'$ is isomorphic to $E$ whence to $C$.

Comment: Sorry, why θ is isom ? What kind of property of θ was used ? Could you specify it ?

Comment: It is the definition. I think you don't understand what is $C,+,-$. Fix $p_0\in C$ then $p\to p_0+p$ is an isomorphism $E\to C$ defined over $\overline{K}$, that's the definition of $C$ and $+$. The only additional thing we ask is that $C$ and $(p_0,p)\to p_0+p,C\times E\to C$ are defined over $K$ and $(p_0+p)+q=p_0+(p+q)$.

Comment: You mean, θ：C→C' can be decomposed into two isomorphism C→E, E→C', so is isom, right ?

Comment: Sure. For any $p_0\in C$ the map $p\to p-p_0$ is an isomorphism $C\to E$, where $-$ is just defined as the inverse of $p\to p_0+p,E\to C$. For $p_0'\in C'$ then $p\to p_0'+p$ is iso $E\to C'$ and so is $p\to p_0'+p+P_0$ for $P_0\in E$.

Comment: So over $\overline{K}$ everything is trivial. The only thing which is a headache is to track over what finite extension of $K$ each point and map is defined. And Silverman shows that it is $H_1(G_K,E)$ which tracks this.

Comment: $E→C,p_0＋P$ is isom over $K(p_0)$, this is proved in prop3.2 of Silverman's book. You claim' $E→C,p_0＋P$ is isom over $ \overline{K}$ is obvious without using prop3.2' ?

Comment: Yes, this is the definition of principal homogeneous space. It is also immediate that it is defined over $K(p_0)$.

Comment: What is your definition of principle homogeneous space of elliptic curve $E/K$ ?

Comment: If your definition is the same as the Silverman's book , I think we cannot escape using the fact that 'Morphism whose fiber of general point is one point is isom'(This is Silverman's prop3.2). Your approach is complete different from that ?

Comment: Sorry, backing to the first problem, your idea is that, both $C$ and $C'$ are isom to $E$ over $ \overline{K}$, so the same as translation map of elliptic curve, so is isom, right ?

Comment: Ok reading Silverman again I don't understand anymore what he is getting at. He doesn't define simply transitive algebraic group action and the action $\mu(Q,P)=Q+P^7$ of $E/\Bbb{F}_{7^2}:y^2=x^3+ix+1$ on $E^7$ isn't an isomorphism (as $j(E)\ne j(E^7)$). This is an algebraic group action and as abstract groups it is simply transitive. The map $P\to \mu(O,P)$ has degree $7$ not $1$.